# cpp- static member and function

Tags: c++, static

I have the following student class with two similar function-
One is static and one is not.

```
class Student
{
    public:
        Student(std::string name_ , int const id_);
        virtual ~Student();
        void addGrade(int const grade2add);//grade above 100
        void removeGrade (int const grade2remove);  //update maxGrade
        void print(); //id, name, grades
        int getStudentMaxGrade();
        static int getMaxGrade();

    private:
        std::string name;  //max 20 chars
        int const id; //5 digits, only digits
        std::vector<int> grades;
        float avg;
        static int  maxGrade;

};
```

The `static int  maxGrade`is initialize with 0.

I implement the function:

```
int Student::maxGrade = 0;

int Student::getStudentMaxGrade()
{
    return *max_element(grades.begin(), grades.end());
}
```

I'm not sure how to implement the static function.
I tried:

```
int Student::getMaxGrade()
{
     maxGrade= *max_element(grades.begin(), grades.end());
    return maxGrade;
}
```

But it doesn't work (doesn't compile)

Comment: `I'm not sure how to implement the ststic function` That rather depends on what you want it to do, which was never adequately explained. Recall that a static member is not tied to a particular object (that's the whole point of `static`). In other words, it cannot refer to any particular individual student.

Comment: @Igor, you mean that it is not tied to a particular instance of an object. It is tied to a particular object, namely `Student`.

Comment: @Chiel `Student` is a class, not an object. If you have `Student s;`, `s` is an object; `Student` isn't.

Comment: @Chiel For most of us an object is an instance of a class _"[and as such, is a location in memory having a value and possibly referenced by an identifier.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science))"_.

Comment: FYI if it does not compile you should include the compiler error(s).

Comment: @sara8 What Igor meant is that you cannot use `grades` in your static function. A static function is not bound to an instance. `grades` does not "exist" in your static function. An example of a static function: `const char* Student::ClassName() { return "Student"; }` The returned value does not depend on an instance.

Comment: Don't you need to initialize `freq_grades` too?

Comment: @ZDF- ok. But I should be able to use the static member maxGrade.

Comment: Yes, maxGrade is static. But grades is used in max_element and thus it won't work.

Comment: ZDF- ok. So  I can remove maxGrade from  max_elemen. But then how can I update the maxGrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your data laid out, each student knows nothing about the grades of the other students, and the class knows nothing about the grades of any particular student. This is good encapsulation, but in order to retrieve the maximum grade of all students, you have to include a bit of logic to keep track of the maximum grade that has been input. Something like this:

```
void Student::addGrade (int const grade) {

    // do the stuff, add the grade

    if (grade > maxGrade)  // Check if the grade is higher than the previous
        maxGrade = grade;  // highest recorded grade and, if so, overwrite it.
}
```

This way, every time a higher grade is input, it becomes the new highest grade, and in that way the class always knows the highest grade without having to keep track of each and every student's grades.

Comment: How about `removeGrade`? @sara8 If what you need is class' `maxGrade`, you need a different design. Consider adding students in a different class that holds a container of students.